# Preserving query parameters when paging jsonschema/hyperschema

Tags: json, rest, pagination, jsonschema

I have a REST API that has quite a few potential query parameters.

The API is reached via a URL like http://example.com/api/object?someParam=10&someOtherParam=20

Where there are a large number of potential parameters.

The response is defined as follows:

```
{
    "title": "Object Collection",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "collection": {
            "title": "Collection",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "$ref": "/schema/object.json"
            }
        },
        "currPage": {
            "title": "Current Page",
            "type": "int"
        },
        "nextPage": {
            "title": "Next Page",
            "type": "int"
        },
        "prevPage": {
            "title": "Previous Page",
            "type": "int"
        },
        "perPage": {
            "title": "Per Page",
            "type": "int"
        },
        "totalCount": {
            "title": "Total Count",
            "type": "integer"
        }
    },
    "links": [
        {
            "title": "Get object collection",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET",
            "href": "/api/object?page={currPage}&perPage={perPage}"
        },
        {
            "title": "Get next page",
            "rel": "next",
            "method": "GET",
            "href": "/api/object?page={nextPage}&perPage={perPage}"
        },
        {
            "title": "Get prev page",
            "rel": "prev",
            "method": "GET",
            "href": "/api/object?page={prevPage}&perPage={perPage}"
        }
    ]
}
```

The issue with the current definition, of course, is that it tosses the query parameters when trying to go to another page via the links.

Is there some good way to account for an arbitrary number of parameters?

In theory I could add all of the possibilities into my response e.g.

```
"properties": {
    ...
    "someParam" : {
        "description": "Some Param"
    },
    "someOtherParam" : {
        "description": "Another param"
    }
}
```

and make my links look like:

```
{
    "title": "Get prev page",
    "rel": "prev",
    "method": "GET",
    "href": "/api/object?page={prevPage}&perPage={perPage}&someParam={someParam}&someOtherParam={someOtherParam}"
}
```

But that quickly becomes cumbersome, particularly given the large number of query parameters.

The URLs will explode, plus the schema would need to updated every time a new query parameter is added.

This strikes me as a pretty common use case, but I haven't been able to find much of anything on it after a fair amount of googling.

Answer (score 2):

So, I picked an approach that seems to work well.  There may well be a better solution, but this is the only one we could come up with that didn't feel really gross.

Specifically, note the introduction of queryString, and its use in the links.

queryString is populated by stripping out the "page" and "perPage" fields from the query string passed in, so as not to repeat those fields.

Also worth noting the **+** before queryString, which prevents it from being URL encoded.

```
{
    "title": "Object Collection",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "collection": {
            "title": "Collection",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "$ref": "/schema/object.json"
            }
        },
        "currPage": {
            "title": "Current Page",
            "type": "int"
        },
        "nextPage": {
            "title": "Next Page",
            "type": "int"
        },
        "prevPage": {
            "title": "Previous Page",
            "type": "int"
        },
        "perPage": {
            "title": "Per Page",
            "type": "int"
        },
        "totalCount": {
            "title": "Total Count",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        //queryString is all of the GET parameters, in their URL form
        // e.g. "someParam=10&anotherParam=20"
        "queryString": {
            "title": "String representing the rest of the query params",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "links": [
        //Added queryString to the end of the hrefs. + sign prevents URL encoding
        {
            "title": "Get object collection",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET",
            "href": "/api/object?page={currPage}&perPage={perPage}&{+queryString}"
        },
        {
            "title": "Get next page",
            "rel": "next",
            "method": "GET",
            "href": "/api/object?page={nextPage}&perPage={perPage}&{+queryString}"
        },
        {
            "title": "Get prev page",
            "rel": "prev",
            "method": "GET",
            "href": "/api/object?page={prevPage}&perPage={perPage}&{+queryString}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope somebody else finds this useful.

Comment: Thanks for this :) I'm going to steal your idea in my own API :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep it in the same thread :)

According to http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-hypermedia.html

```
{
    "title": "News post",
    ...
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "comments",
            "href": "/{id}/comments"
        },
        {
            "rel": "search",
            "href": "/{id}/comments",
            "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "searchTerm": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "itemsPerPage": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "minimum": 10,
                        "multipleOf": 10,
                        "default": 20
                    }
                },
                "required": ["searchTerm"]
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Post a comment",
            "rel": "create",
            "href": "/{id}/comments",
            "method": "POST",
            "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "message": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": ["message"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

> If the client follows the first link, the URI might be expanded to
>   "/15/comments". For the second link, the method is "GET" (the default
>   for HTTP) so a client following this link would add the parameters to
>   the URL to produce something like:
>   "/15/comments?searchTerm=JSON&itemsPerPage=50". The third link defines
>   a possible interaction where a client would POST to a URI (such as
>   "/15/comments"), where the post-data was a JSON representation of the
>   new comment...

So you are supposed to describe query parameters in schema attribute, of the link.

So you could have a separate schema for query object, which you reference in your link, and this would not require additional properties in generic schema.